# Not getting image full path after updating the post in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

When I create a new post,the post image is displaying properly.
But when I edit and update the post image is not displaying.After a little digging from inspect
element I have found that the image is not getting full path-

```
<img src='http://127.0.0.1:8000/Updated_Image.jpg'
```

But the unedited post's path is-

```
<img src='http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/posts/First_Image.jpg'
```

This is my update method in postController.php-

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {



        $this->validate($request,[
            'title'=>'required|max:255',
            'content'=>'required',
            'catagory_id'=>'required'
            ]);

        $post = Post::find($id); 

        if($request->hasFile('featured'))
        {

            $featured = $request->featured;
            $featured_new_name = time() . $featured->getClientOriginalName();
            $featured->move('uploads/posts',$featured_new_name);

            $post->featured = $featured_new_name;
        }

        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->content = $request->content;
        $post->catagory_id = $request->catagory_id;

        $post->save();

        Session::flash('success','Post updated successfully!');

        return redirect()->route('posts');
    }
```

The store function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {


        $this->validate($request,[
            'title'=>'required|max:255',
            'featured'=>'required|image',
            'content'=>'required',
            'catagory_id'=>'required'

        ]);


        $featured = $request->featured;
        $featured_new_name = time().$featured->getClientOriginalName();
        $featured->move('uploads/posts',$featured_new_name);


        $post = Post::create([
            'title'     =>  $request->title,
            'featured'  =>  'uploads/posts/' . $featured_new_name,
            'catagory_id'  =>  $request->catagory_id,
            'content'   =>  $request->content,
            'slug'=> str_slug($request->title)
        ]);


        Session::flash('success', 'A new post is created!');



        return redirect()->back();



    }
```

Post blade file code from where both of the file is displayed-

```
<td> <img src="{{ asset($post->featured) }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}"  width="50px" height="50px"> </td>
```

I have also tried just {{ $post->featured }} but it didn't work.

[Post image after updating,broken image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kj0b.png)

Comment: add your store function too. so, that we can validate your both function are having same path or not

Comment: I think you're problem is here $post->featured = $featured_new_name; please share the store function too.

Comment: for create and update do you use same function ?

Comment: you should need to change one of them like $post->featured = $featured_new_name; with $post->featured = 'uploads/posts'.$featured_new_name;  or like {{ asset( 'uploads/posts'.$post->featured) }}

Comment: replace $post->featured = $featured_new_name; with $post->featured = 'uploads/posts/' . $featured_new_name

Comment: No. Different, post edited with store function.

Comment: Thank you all guys, "$post->featured = 'uploads/posts/' . $featured_new_name". This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while you store the image you have append path with image name see below code

```
$post = Post::create([
            'title'     =>  $request->title,
            'featured'  =>  'uploads/posts/' . $featured_new_name,
            'catagory_id'  =>  $request->catagory_id,
            'content'   =>  $request->content,
            'slug'=> str_slug($request->title)
        ]);
```

while you update image you dont append path as you can see below code

```
if($request->hasFile('featured'))
        {

            $featured = $request->featured;
            $featured_new_name = time() . $featured->getClientOriginalName();
            $featured->move('uploads/posts',$featured_new_name);

            $post->featured = $featured_new_name;
        }
```

so just append path while you update data same as store.